# Is there a way to alphabetize the characters in a string without using any iteration?

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to write a function (using recursion) which can alphabetize a character array. I cannot use any iterative loops in this function and my original attempt at it has flaws. If i cannot use any c++ built in functions as well, I am wondering how possible this task is in the first place

```
string alphaSort(string s) {
    if (s.length() == 0|| s.length()==1) { //end of string
        return s;
    }
    else {

        if (s[0] > s[s.length()-1]) {
            char temp = s[s.length() - 1];
             s[s.length() - 1]=s[0];
             s[0] = temp;
            return  alphaSort(s.substr(0, s.length() - 1) )+s[s.length() - 1];

        }
        else {
            return s[0]+alphaSort(s.substr(1, s.length() - 1));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What was wrong with [C++ Recursive Alphabetizer function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237447/c-recursive-alphabetizer-function) The comment from [@SamVarshavchik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3943312/sam-varshavchik) was that your algorithm was wrong and he pointed out where it failed. Reposting the same code in another question is not helpful. All prior comments are lost. The only way to find the problem is to take out an 8.5x11 sheet of paper and step through your function with your string capturing the state at each level of recursion. (start with `"bca"`)

Comment: Why not something like [Recursive Insertion Sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-insertion-sort/)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet using recursion without using loop based on bubble sort algorithm.

```
void swap(char* src, char* dest) { 
    char temp = *src;
    *src = *dest;
    *dest = temp;
}

void foo(string& p, int i=0, int j = 1) {

    static int n = p.size();    
    if (i == n - 2) return; // exit function if the index is total = (entries -2)
    if (j > n - 1) {
        ++i;  // increment index i to check next lot
        j = i+1;
    }
    if (p[i] > p[j]) swap(&p[i], &p[j]);
    foo(p, i, ++j);
}

int main()
{
    string s="zello";
    foo(s);
    cout << s;
}
```

Comment: Other than that, you may want to add a few sentences on why what the OP was doing wouldn't work and why what you did -- did. What you have will work, but it is very close to a *"Code Only"* answer, which are generally not as useful as those containing at least a brief explanation. But, with the fix of the character/pointer issue, it's worth the UV.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Op don't want to use loop or built-in library, even use of `string::substr` is questionable, not to mention his algorithm. Frankly,  I don't understand his algorithm.

Comment: It is quite confusing. Yours is easy to follow, but it may help the OP if you explain what you base case is, your exit clause and what you are doing until your exit clause is satisfied. You could probably do it with a good set of comments in the code, and maybe a sentence or two at the bottom.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Sure. I edit to add few comments in the code.

Comment: I'm getting output "axby" for input `s="xyab"` using your code. Is that expected?

Comment: @גלעדברקן    Edited, Please check again

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation on your idea.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string f(string s) {
  if (s.length() < 2)
    return s;

  string sorted = f(s.substr(1, s.length() - 1));

  if (s[0] <= sorted[0])
    return string(1, s[0]) + sorted;
  else
    return f(string(1, sorted[0]) + s[0] + sorted.substr(1, sorted.length() - 1));
}

int main()
{
  string s = "yxab";
  cout << f(s);
}
```